# Javascript: Compare backgroundColor set by javascript

Tags: javascript, css, background, comparison

How can compare the background color of an element, when the color is set with javascript, I want a function that toggles the backgroundColor:

```
function toggleBgColor() {
    if(document.getElementById("id").style.backgroundColor === "blue"){
        document.getElementById("ide").style.backgroundColor = "red");
    }else{
        document.getElementById("ide").style.backgroundColor = "blue");
    }
}
```

The problem is that the comparison is always false, so my background is always blue, but it want the color to switch from blue to red and vice versa when the function is called

Comment: You'd have to use inline css for this to initially work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Window.getComputedStyle()` — https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle.

Answer (score 0):

The backgroundColor property can get tricky with various representations of color. Consider changing classes instead:

**JavaScript**

```
function toggleBgColor() {
    var el = document.getElementById("id");
    var hasBlue = el.classList.contains('blue');
    el.classList.toggle('blue', !hasBlue);
    el.classList.toggle('red', hasBlue);
}
```

**CSS**

```
.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
.red {
  background-color:red;
}
```

Or more semantically correct:

**JavaScript**

```
function toggleBgColor() {
    document.getElementById("id").classList.toggle('selected');
}
```

**CSS**

```
#id {
    background-color:red;
}
#id.selected {
    background-color:blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply add a class that gets toggled?

```
function toggleBgClass() {
    var element = document.getElementById('id');

    if (element.classList.contains('blue')) {
        element.classList.add('blue');
        element.classList.remove('red');
    }
    else {
        element.classList.add('red');
        element.classList.remove('blue');
    }
}
```

Now, in your CSS:

```
.blue {
    background-color: blue;
}

.red {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have written the incorrect code.
The correct code is

```
    function toggleBgColor()
    {
       if(document.getElementById("ptag").style.backgroundColor === "blue")
       {
         document.getElementById("ptag").style.backgroundColor = "red";
       }
       else
       {   
         document.getElementById("ptag").style.backgroundColor = "blue";
       }
    };
```

Html File

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/backgroundtry.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id="ptag" style="background-color:blue;">
            Hi How are you
        </p>
        <a class="mybutton" onclick="toggleBgColor();">
            Change Color
        </a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is jQuery, right? I don't want to use jQuery right now, because I think you don't really know a programming language if you can only use it with a framework

Comment: Well there is just click function and ready which is of jQuery here,Just replace with your javascript onclick function and ready with onload and the rest remains the same

Comment: Did you try that, when I did `console.log(item.style.backgroundColor);` i got `undefined`?

Comment: It works exactly the way you need.Let me know what error are you facing.Just copy paste my code and tell me if there is an issue